# Is it necessary to set up apache, php and mysql?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, mysql, localhost

I am developing `mean-stack` websites on my Mac. So I will need to use `http://localhost:3000/...`, `https://localhost:3000/...` to test the websites, and eventually `http://localhost/localFile` and `https://localhost/localFile` to access local files on the machine.

To this end, does anyone know if it is necessary to set up `apache`, `php` and `mysql` there? I am confused, because I only code `mean-stack` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set up anything you don't need.

[MEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)) dosen't really need or use PHP or MySQL - so no, unless you decided to use MySQL instead of Mongo or PHP instead of node.js.

If you find you need it, you can always install it later

Comment: Do I need to set up `apache`?

Comment: Additionally, what should I do to enable `http://localhost/localFile`?

Comment: You wouldn't need [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369865/running-node-js-in-apache) *unless* you set it up as a proxy - which might incidentally let you do what you want with the right settings? I run nginx or lighttpd mostly